# in Quarkus, can I merge files that have the same name in many dependencies, ie typesafe config files?

Tags: quarkus, typesafe-config

I have a file called reference.conf that exists in many dependencies and derives from typesafe config (https://github.com/lightbend/config)

I use Quarkus for my application.

When Quarkus builds the uber-jar it keeps only one of these files (the one from the last dependency that it parses).

How can I merge all this files to a single one?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this commit in Quarkus https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/commit/b3d3788ae92542d5fb39d89488890e16d64cec90 "Introduce UberJarMergedResourceBuildItem and UberJarIgnoredResourceBuildItem",
that works from release https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/releases/tag/1.13.4.Final we can create an extension in Quarkus and use it to merge any resource we want to.
Many thanks to George Gastaldi for this.

To create the extension is quite easy, as I did also for first time for this feature.

```
c:\projects> mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.4.Final:create-extension -N -DgroupId=myproject.quarkus -DextensionId=quarkus-files-extension -DwithoutTests
```

Done, the extension has been created with all the needed maven projects, configuration etc. Now, edit the file of the extension

```
c:\projects\quarkus-files-extension\deployment\src\main\java\myproject\quarkus\files\extension\deployment\QuarkusFilesExtensionProcessor.java
```

add the BuildStep: UberJarMergedResourceBuildItem

```
class QuarkusFilesExtensionProcessor {

    private static final String path = "reference.conf";

    @BuildStep
    UberJarMergedResourceBuildItem feature() {              
        return new UberJarMergedResourceBuildItem(path);
    }
}
```

Build the Quarkus extension maven project, ie

```
c:\projects\quarkus-files-extension> mvn clean install
```

Now add the extension to your project that needs the merging by either executing

```
c:\project\mybigproject> mvn quarkus:add-extension -Dextensions="myproject.quarkus:quarkus-files-extension"
```

It simply adds the dependency of the extension in your pom.xml

That's it, next time that you build the uber-jar in the project, it merges all the reference.conf files to a single one.

The only thing missing is a verbose message, which is not possible with the current version,
You can notice that it works, by either of course checking the reference.conf in the uber-jar
or the following message is now missing from the build log

```
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep] Dependencies with duplicate files detected. The dependencies [groupId1:artifact1::jar:1.0(compile), groupId2:artifact2::jar:1.0(compile)] contain duplicate files, e.g. reference.conf
```

They also offer a feature to ignore files with a certain name, with the BuildItem UberJarIgnoredResourceBuildItem. You create an extension exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Doesn't this call for a generic extension (from the Quarkus project) for which I only need to configure the path?

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by Andreas is fine for files that can be appended sequentially, however that's not true for XML or JSON files, for example.

For these cases, it's preferable to perform the merge in a `@BuildStep` method in an extension and produce a `GeneratedResourceBuildItem` instead.

Here is an example using [XmlCombiner](https://github.com/atteo/xml-combiner):

```java
    @BuildStep
    void uberJarMergedResourceBuildItem(BuildProducer<GeneratedResourceBuildItem> generatedResourcesProducer,
            PackageConfig packageConfig) {
        if (packageConfig.isUberJar()) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                XmlCombiner combiner = new XmlCombiner();
                List<URL> resources = Collections
                        .list(getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/wsdl.plugin.xml"));
                for (URL resource : resources) {
                    try (InputStream is = resource.openStream()) {
                        combiner.combine(is);
                    }
                }
                combiner.buildDocument(baos);
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | TransformerException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            generatedResourcesProducer.produce(new GeneratedResourceBuildItem("META-INF/wsdl.plugin.xml", baos.toByteArray()));
        }
    }
```

See a test in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/17199